# Fetching html instead import js module - why or why not?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, fetch, single-page-application

I have a technical debate ongoing and a decision needs to be taken, but I hardly have any facts to decide on, only opinions like

> "That's not the way one should work" or "This is bad practise"

But this doesn't help me to decide on the following problem:

We are to build a SPA not using any frameworks or packages like webpack, so from scratch / vanillaJS. Basically I have an index.html loading a main.js as entry point which will then load the page requested via Hash in the browsers location replacing the content of a `<div id="content">...</div>`. So far so good, just a simple SPA.

Now the question is whether to:

> 1. Load standalone .html files (e.g. somepage.html) via fetch (remember no webpack, all vanilla...) and DOM parse them, extract any script tags (e.g. `<script src="somepage.js" type="module">`) and put the remaining html code in the `<div id="content">...</div>`, add scripts to the head and so on...

or

> 2. Have a simple router in our index.js which has ES6 module imports for each available page, so basically import a JS module which will have a html template somehow referenced (as a string or loaded via fetch) and add HTML to the `<div id="content">...</div>`, call the JS modules init()-function and so on...

I would always tend to say: Use the second way, avoid fetching full html pages. But why?

My only arguments so far:

- why fetching more data than necessary - the most of the html (like ...) is unnecessary overhead
- do not switch between languages more than absolutely necessary, since in way 1 you load HTML (index.html), then JS (index.js), then again HTML (somePage.html), then again JS (somePage.js) and every switch means interfaces need to be considered and handled, so they could mean less control over your code

But that can't be it and doesn't really convince me - what are the hard facts why or why not doing this ways?

(and sorry if this is not an appropriate question - I'm just new here)

Comment: Yeah, the first approach feels wrong. It involves doing *more work*. The whole get HTML -> "unpack" the HTML into scripts and page content -> work on this suggest that *fundamentally* that HTML "container" is not the correct thing to use here. With that said...I've actually worked on a system that did that. It's possible to do it correctly but at least in our case it was *weird*. Navigating to another page meant that the loaded scripts remain, so if you navigate back you get into a bizarre state. Which meant that there was an entire framework for loading/reloading content.

Comment: Describes my problem really good: "Feels wrong..."
Thanks for sharing your experience, I'll check on the point with loaded Scripts - think this could be important, since a handling mechanism will be necessary here. And also brings up: If scripts are not unloaded properly - what's about namespace pollution at Javascript top level? (in case there are not modules imported).

Comment: To be clear, we didn't have "unloading". We had a convoluted mechanic where you'd *load* a page which fetches the scripts it has and registers a main module in a top level map indexed by page. This prevented double loading but `.initialise(firstTime)` would still be called on it where the parameter is a boolean. The module is then responsible for whether or not it has to do any cleanup or any other work if it's re-initialised. That was just our scripts, though - Bootstrap modals were a huge problem as they were added/removed outside the main content area. The way that works is that the

Comment: template for the modal is part of the page (the one you fetch) but hidden. Opening a modal *automatically moved its DOM element elsewhere*. Particularly, outside the `#main` element where included pages were dumped. So, if you go to page A, then open a modal, go to page B, go back to page A, you now have two copies of the modal. The whole usage of modals was just edge cases, frankly, each needing a "new and exciting" approach, especially since some where incompatible. And that's just one example of 3rd party code being impacted. I'm glad that project was scrapped.